# Combining bootstrap grid options to simplify long div classes

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using the current version of Bootstrap (v3.3.1). Looking at the grid options, there are many classes to use considering different media breakpoints.

The application I'm working on requires to work on all media type so I have to use all the grid options... `.col-xs-`   `.col-sm-`  `.col-md-`  `.col-lg-`

Typing these into one div class seems a bit excessive and ugly. Is there a way I can combine all 4 grid options to work depending on the media size?

For example, if the class will stretch 12 columns in all media views...can I group them together within a CSS file like so...

```
.col-12 {
  .col-lg-12{}
  .col-sm-12{}
  .col-xs-12{}
}
```

And then within the HTML doc, have my div class like so...

```
<div class="col-12">
```

instead of doing something like this...

```
<div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to use all the options. You can simply use the `col-xs` option and it'll remain the same on any screen size.

So, to summarize, this:

```
<div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12"></div>
```

is exactly the same as this:

```
<div class="col-xs-12"></div>
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/degoeym/b0e827j6/)**

Comment: If you don't mind me furthering this question... say I have a set of classes I'll always use (almost like a default class). Like `<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">` is there a way to do something similar to my original question for a situation like this?

Comment: I totally mind you asking me questions on SO. :P Anyway, I honestly wouldn't know off the top of my head, and since it's a related but different question, I'd suggest asking it in a new question.

Comment: @mikeymurph77 - no. The classes are specific to their media queries so you can't combine and <div class="col-md-4"> would do exactly the same thing in your example. The width is always 100% UNDER the last min-width class used and always the percentage of the screen (33.3333% for col-X-4) OVER the min-width used. So col-md-4 will be the SAME percentage of the container as col-lg-4. Please learn the basics of mobile first CSS.

Comment: @Christina Do you have any resources for him to learn the basics of mobile first CSS?

Comment: Also, the col-X-12 is not necessary unless it's between widths, if something is always full width, there's no need to employ the grid system. See the doc examples here: http://getbootstrap.com/examples/grid/ - read the note: "No grid classes are necessary for full-width elements."

Comment: A very valid point, but he was asking if there was a way to use the grid system without having to add classes for all width levels, so that's what I provided.

Comment: @MattD -- comment not directed at you, it's to point out that it's really not necessary to specify col-X-12 most of the time.